# Deleting a specific item from text file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I want to delete a specific items in a text file in python. for example, say in my text file I have:

```
<td>Zulfahmi</td>, <td>081354</td>, <td>Fachrial</td>, <td>0823</td>, <td>1203188</td>
```

I want to delete tag `<td>` to show:

```
Zulfahmi, 081354, Fachrial, 0823, 203188
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Please make a tiny effort searching for an existing answer before asking.

Comment: You want to delete tags or show the values in the tag?

Answer (score 4):

Just use regular expression

```
from re import sub
text = """<td>Zulfahmi</td>, <td>081354</td>, <td>Fachrial</td>, <td>0823</td>, <td>1203188</td>"""
text = sub('<(/*)td>', '', text)
```

or simply use replace

```
text = """<td>Zulfahmi</td>, <td>081354</td>, <td>Fachrial</td>, <td>0823</td>, <td>1203188</td>"""
text = text.replace('<td>', '').replace('</td>', '')
```

**EDIT**

To use it in a file

```
from re import sub
with open(filname,'r+') as f:
    text = f.read()
    f.write(sub('<(/*)td>','',text))
```

Comment: I think the question is not about replacing a substring from a given string but to replace it in a text file.

Answer (score 1):

Or:

```
import re
with open(filname,'r') as f:
    s=f.read()
    s2=re.sub('</*td>','',s)
with open(filename2,'w') as f:
    f.write(s2)
```

File:

```
Zulfahmi, 081354, Fachrial, 0823, 1203188
```

If you're doing it to a string, do:

```
import re
s="<td>Zulfahmi</td>, <td>081354</td>, <td>Fachrial</td>, <td>0823</td>, <td>1203188</td>"
print(re.sub('</*td>','',s))
```